# compare two binary search trees and decide if a subtree is in a binary search tree

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have tried to develop a solution for two problems, the first one is for deciding if two Binary Search Trees (BST) are the same, and the second one is to decide whether a subtree is in BST with all decedent nodes.

This is my solution, and I get some wrong results, and I don't know where the problem is.

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
} Node;


int compare_bst(Node* root_p, Node* root_q) {
    if (root_p && root_q) {
        if (root_p->data != root_q->data)
            return 0;
        compare_bst(root_p->left, root_q->left);
        compare_bst(root_p->right, root_q->right);
    }
    return 1;
}

int has_subtree(Node* root, Node* sub_root) {
    if (root){
        if (compare_bst(root, sub_root))
            return 1;
        has_subtree(root->left, sub_root);
        has_subtree(root->right, sub_root);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

```
Node* insert(Node* root, int elm) { // -V
    if (!root) {
        root = create_node_bst(elm);
    }
    else if (elm <= root->data) {
        root->left = insert(root->left, elm);
    }
    else {
        root->right = insert(root->right, elm);
    }
    return root;
}

void level_order(Node* root) { // visit all children before grand children [BFS]
    if (!is_empty(root)) {
        Queue *q = malloc(sizeof *q);
        if (q) {
            *q = queue_init;
            enqueue(q, root);
            while (!is_empty_q(q)) {
                Node* cur = front(q);
                printf("%d ", cur->data);
                if (cur->left != NULL)
                    enqueue(q, cur->left);
                if (cur->right != NULL)
                    enqueue(q, cur->right);
                dequeue(q);
            }
        }
        free(q);
    }
}

int compare_bst(Node* root_p, Node* root_q) {
    if (root_p && root_q) {
        if (root_p->data != root_q->data)
            return 0;
        return compare_bst(root_p->left, root_q->left) && compare_bst(root_p->right, root_q->right);
    }
    return !root_p && !root_q;
}

int has_subtree(Node* root, Node* sub_root) {
    if (root){
        if (compare_bst(root, sub_root))
            return 1;
        return has_subtree(root->left, sub_root) || has_subtree(root->right, sub_root);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    #define MAX 7
    int n = MAX;
    BST bst1 = bst_init;
    BST bst2 = bst_init;
    Node* bst1_root = bst1.root;
    Node* bst2_root = bst2.root;
    int arr[MAX] = {4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        bst1_root = insert(bst1_root, arr[i]);
       // bst2_root = insert(bst2_root, arr[i]);
        if (i > 4) {
            bst2_root = insert(bst2_root, arr[i]);
        }
       // else
    //         bst2_root = insert(bst2_root, 9);      
    }
        
    
    printf("bst1 and bst2 are the same: %d \n", compare_bst(bst1_root, bst2_root));
    printf("bst1_root has bst2 subtree: %d", has_subtree(bst1_root, bst2_root));
}
```

I get a wrong result for `has_subtree`, why is that?

Comment: Please provide the code with which you have determined a result is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ignoring the result that comes back from the recursive calls, so those calls are made with no benefit.

In the first function **both** recursive calls must return 1 for the end result to be 1. In the second function **either** recursive call must return 1 for that.

Also, when one tree is empty and the other not, then you should not return 1.

Here is a correction:

```
int compare_bst(Node* root_p, Node* root_q) {
    if (root_p && root_q) {
        if (root_p->data != root_q->data)
            return 0;
        return compare_bst(root_p->left, root_q->left) &&
               compare_bst(root_p->right, root_q->right);
    }
    return !root_p && !root_q; // Require that both are NULL
}

int has_subtree(Node* root, Node* sub_root) {
    if (root){
        if (compare_bst(root, sub_root))
            return 1;
        return has_subtree(root->left, sub_root) ||
               has_subtree(root->right, sub_root);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can shorten this by combining the different conditions into one expression:

```
int compare_bst(Node* root_p, Node* root_q) {
    return root_p && root_q
         ? root_p->data == root_q->data && 
           compare_bst(root_p->left, root_q->left) &&
           compare_bst(root_p->right, root_q->right)
         : !root_p && !root_q;
}

int has_subtree(Node* root, Node* sub_root) {
    return !!root &&
           (   compare_bst(root, sub_root) ||
               has_subtree(root->left, sub_root) ||
               has_subtree(root->right, sub_root)
           );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was something I didn't pay attention to, thanks again

Comment: Maybe I need to `return !sub_root;` instead of `0` for `has_subtree` in case we consider a `NULL` subtree to be part of the a given tree, right?

Comment: That is a boundary case which could be open for debate (a matter of opinion). If you consider that the empty tree is a subtree of any other tree, then yes, test this condition at the very start and avoid making any recursive calls, as they wont influence this outcome. If you choose to say that an empty tree is never a subtree of another tree, then do the same but return 0.

Comment: I see, it makes sense. I updated above, I get a wrong answer, and I have no single idea why, I am comparing `bst1_root` with `bst2_root` which is just `7->9` tree, and says the latter is part of the first one, which is not correct

Comment: I don't see a problem there. `bst1_root` has a subtree `7->9` and that is exactly what `bst2_root` is.

Comment: Actually not, `bst1_root` has this subtree `7->6 | 7->9` and a subtree is all the decedents of the root. `bst2_root` doesn't have 6 on the left. Moreover, the code is supposed to check for the root and all decedents, not just one side view, which is puzzling to me how it returns 1, when it should return 0, in the comparison, it can return 1 only if the condition of `&&` is met

Comment: `bst1_root` has `4` as root with two subtrees below it. One is `1->2->3` (not relevant) and the other is `6->7->9`, since 6 is inserted before 7 is, and so it is not as you say that there is a `7->6`. Unless of course you have balancing logic that you didn't share in your question...

Comment: `return compare_bst(root_p->left, root_q->left) && compare_bst(root_p->right, root_q->right);` should return 0 from `return !root_p && !root_q;`, as there is no left in the subtree, but there is in the the other one,

Comment: I mean, see this `if (i > 4) {` only `7->9` is inserted in `bst2_root`

Comment: Look, I implemented this. See it run on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma757094445459839#main.c). Surely `if (i > 4)` is also true when `6` is inserted. And by the time `7` is inserted it follows the path to `if (i > 6)` and inserts it below the `6`.

Comment: Ok, I added my insert

Comment: Yes, that `insert` is fine. Please read my comments above. 7 is a child of 6.

Comment: But when I print the level order of `bst1_root` it is this `4 1 6 2 7 3 9`

Comment: So why do you think that level order sequence shows that 6 is a *child* of 7? That cannot be, because 6 is listed *earlier* than 7. I tell you: 7 is a child of 6. Just debug and check. The code I linked to, prints the in-order sequence with indenting so there is no doubt what the shape of the tree is. I think we should stop this ping pong now.

Comment: No no it's not ping pong, thanks for your time, I am just confused myself, I added the level order function, and it really prints 4 1 6 2 7 3 9, and what you said is right. My in order prints the same result as yours

Comment: It seems I was relying on the level order to get the shape of the tree, turned out my level order is wrong! I am very sorry :(

Comment: The level order is fine though. But your conclusions from it were not right.